# Ionic infinite scroll with custom content

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to show custom loader inside of ionic infinite like this

```
 <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <spinner [color]="'white'"></spinner>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

But the problem is that then spinner is always visible since I see that infinite scroll has property `state` and its modifying attribute of ion-infinite-scroll-content to setting state property and there is css which hides it.

My question is does any body has done any custom spinners or only way to have custom spinner is to use css class?

So basically it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created feature request, and it was moved to private pool. For now i am back to standard spinners